# pandoc SOMETIMES fails to find utf8.md file

Tags: parallel-processing, r-markdown, pandoc

I have an R code, which renders several rmarkdown HTML reports in a loop. 
This is roughly the code in the loop:

```
knitr::knit_meta(class=NULL, clean = TRUE)
rmarkdown::render(input =paste0("10_ReportingHTML/10_01_ReportingPortfoliosHTML.Rmd"), output_file = paste0(reportPath), params = list(MyDataFrame = MyDataFrame[i]))
```

By MyDataFrame[i] I mean that the input data.frame is different in every loop iteration.

I let this code run on an AWS server, parallel on several cores. By parallel I mean, that my code runs simultaneously in several threads, but with different input data.

Sometimes it runs without problems, but sometimes the following error occurs:

```
pandoc: 10_01_ReportingPortfoliosHTML.utf8.md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Do you have any idea why this happens and why not regularly?

**Update:**

After some further investigation, I have found out that all the parallel threads use the same working directory and are creating knitr meta data with the same names. That is why if one thread cleans all the meta data, it also disappears in other threads. Moreover, if I don't clean the meta data, I get a crazy mix of the data of different threads:
I have solved it in an ugly way by copying the code for each parallel process in a separate directory with unique name and setting it as a working directory for this process. After the process is done, this unique temporary created working directory is erased:

```
libPath = "Some/Unique/directory"
system(paste0("cp ", R_FUNCTIONS_PATH, "10_ReportingHTML/10_01_ReportingPortfoliosHTML.Rmd ", libPath, "/"), intern = T)
rmarkdown::render(input =paste0(libPath, "/10_01_ReportingPortfoliosHTML.Rmd"), output_file = paste0(reportPath), params = list(MyDataFrame = MyDataFrame[i]))
knitr::knit_meta(class=NULL, clean = TRUE)
system(paste0("rm -r ", libPath), intern = T)
```

My updated question: is there any other possibility to set a working directory to the location different from the "input" argument from `render()` function (somewhere different to .Rmd code location)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further investigation, I have found out that all the parallel threads use the same working directory and are creating knitr meta data with the same names. That is why if one thread cleans all the meta data, it also disappears in other threads. Moreover, if I don't clean the meta data, I get a crazy mix of the data of different threads: I have solved it in an ugly way by copying the code for each parallel process in a separate directory with unique name and setting it as a working directory for this process. After the process is done, this unique temporary created working directory is erased:

```
libPath = "Some/Unique/directory"

system(paste0("cp ", R_FUNCTIONS_PATH, "10_ReportingHTML/10_01_ReportingPortfoliosHTML.Rmd ", libPath, "/"), intern = T)

rmarkdown::render(input =paste0(libPath, "/10_01_ReportingPortfoliosHTML.Rmd"), 
                  output_file = paste0(reportPath), 
                  params = list(MyDataFrame = MyDataFrame[i]))

knitr::knit_meta(class=NULL, clean = TRUE)

system(paste0("rm -r ", libPath), intern = T)
```